# Displaying jinja2 form fields based on attribute value

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm working on a flask app and using flask-wtf to help manage my forms.

There are 2 ways to register on my site -  Either with or without an email token.

If the email has been confirmed the user gets an email containing:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/register/ImNsdWVtYXJpbmUzQG1haWxpbmF0b3IuY29tIg.Ca9oUQ.bRJmGYQ1wNqfcQFx1pYyoCEy2oM
```

Otherwise on the site itself the user could click on:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:5000/register
```

The following code can handle both cases:

```
@blueprint.route("/register/", defaults={'token': ''}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@blueprint.route("/register/<token>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register(token):
    form = RegisterForm(request.form, csrf_enabled=False)
    email = confirm_token(token)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_user = User.create(username=form.username.data,
                              email=form.email.data,
                               password=form.password.data,
                               active=True)
return render_extensions('public/register.html', form=form , email=email)
```

My form class looks like:

```
class RegisterForm(Form):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email(), Length(min=6, max=40)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=6, max=40)])
```

I have a jinja2 form template that looks like:

```
{% from "macros.html" import render_field  %}
<div class="container-narrow">
  <h1>Register</h1>
    <br/>
       <form id="registerForm" class="form form-register" method="POST" action="" role="form">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% if field.label!='Email' or email=='False' %}
                {{ render_field(field) }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <p><input class="btn btn-default btn-submit" type="submit" value="Register"></p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and a jinja2 macro that looks like:

```
{% macro render_field(field)%}

<div class="form-group">
{#                {{field.label}}#}
                {{field(placeholder=field.label.text, class_="form-control")}}
</div>

{% endmacro %}
```

Right now this code works to display all the fields in the registerForm class. I'd like to modify/filter it so that if a token is used, I would like to display and validate only 2 form fields (username, password) . If no token - all 3 . How can this be done?

edit: switching

```
{% if field.label!='Email' or email=='False' %}
```

to

```
{% if field.label.text!='Email' or email=='False' %}
```

got it working

Comment: I've made an edit where I tried adding an if statement to the form template that should render any field not labeled 'Email' or render it when the passed in 'email' variable is false, But its not working ,the Email form field is rendered both with and without the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use inheritance, we'd define 2 form classes:

```py
class TokenRegisterForm(Form):

    username = StringField('Username', 
        validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=25)])

    password = PasswordField('Password', 
        validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=6, max=40)])


class RegisterForm(TokenRegister):

    email = StringField('Email',
        validators=[DataRequired(), Email(), Length(min=6, max=40)])
```

Then we'd modify the view to choose a form to use based on the existence of a token:

```py
def register(token):
    """Register a user"""

    # Create the registration form based on the presence of a token. If the user 
    # has specified a valid token then we can use that to get retrieve their 
    # email address, if not we need to the registration form to ask it.
    email = confirm_token(token)
    if email:
        form = TokenRegisterForm(request.form, csrf_enabled=False)
    else
        form = RegisterForm(request.form, csrf_enabled=False)

    # Validate the user's submission
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        # Collate the details for the new user
        user_details = form.data
        user_details['active'] = True
        if email:
            user_details['email'] = email

        # Create the new user
        new_user = User.create(**user_details)

    return render_extensions('public/register.html', form=form, email=email)
```

Finally we'd modify the Jinja2 template removing the loop (as it's such a short form):

```
{% from "macros.html" import render_field  %}

<div class="container-narrow">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <br/>
    <form 
        class="form form-register" 
        id="registerForm" 
        method="POST"
        role="form"
        >
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ render_field(field.username) }}
        {% if form.email %}
            {{ render_field(field.email) }}
        {% endif %}
        {{ render_field(field.password) }}
        <p>
            <input 
                class="btn btn-default btn-submit" 
                type="submit" 
                value="Register">
        </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I'm a beginner so its great to see how you approach this. BTW, the original problem answer is in the edit above. As an aside, I have an old version of pycharm that does not have the jinja2 support so debugging the template has been difficult.Any advice on flask template debugging?

Comment: Hi user61629, in general I find the debug output of Flask to be pretty comprehensive and I've not looked to use anything else. I'm relatively new to Flask as well so I don't know much about what's out there however there is a django style deubbing toolbar (http://flask-debugtoolbar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which might be what you're looking for?