# Comparison operator error with flask jinja2 template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

[image]

I'm following up on [Displaying jinja2 form fields based on attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636678/displaying-jinja2-form-fields-based-on-attribute-value). I'm working with flask and jinja2 templates

My form class looks like:

```
class RegisterForm(Form):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email(), Length(min=6, max=40)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=6, max=40)])
```

I have a jinja2 form template that looks like:

```
{% from "macros.html" import render_field  %}
<div class="container-narrow">
<h1>Register</h1>
<br/>
<form id="registerForm" class="form form-register" method="POST" action="" role="form">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% print(field.label != 'Email')%}
            {% print(field.label)%}
            {% print(field.name)%}
            {% if field.label!='Email' or email=='False' %}
                {{ render_field(field) }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <p><input class="btn btn-default btn-submit" type="submit" value="Register"></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

and a jinja2 macro that looks like:

```
{% macro render_field(field)%}

<div class="form-group">
{#                {{field.label}}#}
                {{field(placeholder=field.label.text, class_="form-control")}}
</div>

{% endmacro %}
```

You can see the output in the screenshot. I don't understand why:

```
{% print(field.label != 'Email')%}
```

is True for the Email field

Comment: Perhaps need unicode string as in u'Email'? I'm just grasping at straws there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `field.label` returns `Label` not a string. Hence your comparison always yields `True` (which is correct).

I have similar email form in my code, here's an example:

```
(Pdb++) form.email.label
Label('email', u'Email')
(Pdb++) form.email.label != 'email'
True
(Pdb++) form.email.label != 'Email'
True
(Pdb++) type(form.email.label)
<class 'wtforms.fields.core.Label'>
(Pdb++) form.email.label.text
u'Email'
(Pdb++) form.email.label.field_id
'email'
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps me. I can see that you are using pdb. I have an old version of pycharm that does not have the jinja2 support so debugging the template has been difficult. I had to resort to print statements, Can you offer any advice or good articles to read on how you set this up?

Comment: I just use pdb++ or ipdb with console to debug my code, not PyCharm. In your case I wasn't debugging the template - I've just set up debugger in my view function which has email form in it and checked what a field label is :)