# how return result in label using python flask

Tags: python, html, http, flask

When I search for  data, how do I return this data to Label?

HTML:

```
<form action='/' method='POST'>
  <label for="server number">server number</label>
  <input class="server_number" type="text" name='server_number' id='server_number' placeholder="Enter server_number">
  <br>
  <label for="meter number">meter number</label>
  <input class="meter_number" type="text" name='meter_number' id='meter_number' placeholder="Enter meter_number">
  </br>
  <div class="=form-group">
    <button class="=btn btn-primary" type="submit"> check</button>
  </div>

  <label for="result">result</label>
  <input type="text" name='result' id='result' placeholder="result">
</form>
```

Python:

```py
def header():
  ganache_url = "HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"
  web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ganache_url))
  web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]# abi = json.loads('[ ]')
  address = web3.toChecksumAddress("0x3a9AE7Ac1786677D41C3f6A340577Ea42216c81a")
  contract = web3.eth.contract(address = address, abi = abi)
  if request.method == "POST":
    server_number = request.form["server_number"]
    meter_number = request.form["meter_number"]
    result = contract.functions.get(int(server_number), int(meter_number)).call()
    print(result)
    return render_template('header.html')
  return render_template('header.html')
```

As it appears in this picture, I am searching for certain values. I want to return the data (result) to the results label, Also, when I search, I enter two values, but three values are returned from (result). How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't heard of template rendering, which is simply where data passed from the back-end is applied on the front-end. Flask supports Jinja - you should start with the documentation [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/)

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636678/displaying-jinja2-form-fields-based-on-attribute-value) demonstrates exactly the process to apply the value to the result table. [This](https://pythonise.com/series/learning-flask/jinja-template-design) is also a good walk-through example.

Comment: `   result = contract.functions.get(int(server_number), int(meter_number)).call() `
Here is the search process, where I enter two values and return 3 values. how can I do that .
I want to return these values in the label results

Comment: Can you be a bit more elaborate? You can edit and add it to your question with relevant details.